# Robot Framework: Get Lines containing exact string/pattern match

Tags: python-3.x, regex, robotframework

How to match the exact string **abc** ?? I want to retrieve first 3 lines. 
Similarly I want to retrieve lines containing **abcmnp** next.

```
ab1049-abc-0-0
ab1049-abc-1-0
ab1049-abc-2-0
kf-ab-1049-kafka-abc-0
kf-ab-1049-kafka-abc-1
kf-ab-1049-kafka-abc-2
zk-ab-1049-kafka-abc-0
zk-ab-1049-kafka-abc-1
zk-ab-1049-kafka-abc-2
ab1049-abcmnp-0-0
ab1049-abcmnp-1-0
ab1049-abcmnp-2-0
ab1049-abcpqrs-0-0
ab1049-abcpqrs-1-0
ab1049-abcpqrs-2-0
```

I tried below regex with no success.
Please do clarify. Thanks!

```
${match}=         Get Lines Matching Regexp       ${output}       r'\babc\\b'
Log ${match}

${match}=         Get Lines Matching Regexp       ${output}       ^.*abc.*$
Log     ${match}

${match}=         Get Regexp Matches       ${output}       /^abc$/
Log ${match}
```

Comment: You say you want to match the exact string `abc`, but none of the lines have exactly `abc`. Also, you say you want the first three lines. Those three contain the string `abc`, but so do the next six lines. Why should `abc` match the first three lines but not the next six?

Comment: @BryanOakley: Thanks you. Sorry I had missed your comments.
I want to parse the O/P and separate the variables as below.
Ex: 
GROUP1: ab1049-abc-0-0, ab1049-abc-1-0, ab1049-abc-2-0
GROUP2: kf-ab-1049-kafka-abc-0, kf-ab-1049-kafka-abc-1, kf-ab-1049-kafka-abc-2
GROUP3: ab1049-abcmnp-0-0, ab1049-abcmnp-1-0, ab1049-abcmnp-2-0
etc.,.

Can you please suggest what keyword can be used for this ?